# Display user input without asterisk

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Can somebody help me, because the user input is displayed as asterisk and what i need to do is display what user have input. Here is my Code and it is working, i just need the characters ti be displayed.

```
dosseg
.model small
.stack
.data

pwd db 'assembly'
msg1 db 10, 13, 'Correct Password', 10, 13, '$'
msg2 db 10, 13, 'Incorrect Password', 10, 13, '$'

 .code
 main: mov ax, @data
 mov ds, ax
 mov bx, offset pwd

 mov cx, 8
x: mov ah, 8
 int 21h

 push ax
 push [bx]
 inc bx

 mov ah, 2 
mov dl, '*'
 int 21h
 loop x

 mov cx, 8
y: pop ax
 pop bx
 cmp al, bl
 jne error
 loop y

 mov ah, 9
 mov dx, offset msg1
 int 21h
exit: mov ah, 4ch
 int 21h

error: mov ah, 9
 mov dx, offset msg2
 int 21h

 jmp exit
 End main
```

Comment: `mov dl, '*'` then why I you printing it ?

Comment: It might be a good idea to first understand what you are doing instead of copying random code from the internet.  Use DOS function `INT21/AH=01h` instead of `INT21/AH=08h` for terminal input with echo and drop all that weird echo logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the word `assembly` then you need to print it. Your code as-is just prints asterisks in a loop.

```
mov bx, offset pwd
mov cx,8
mov ah,2

printloop:
mov dl, byte ptr [bx]   ;read from the address "pwd"
inc bx                  ;advance to next letter
int 21h
loop printloop

jmp $
```